# Would you ride with this tire with cuts in the sidewall?

Tags: tire

I have a next to unused GP5000 road tire, 25mm, which unfortunately has three cuts in the sidewall. I would like to ask, if it these constitutes a safety problem - or if they rather are to be looked upon like regular cuts in the tread.
What is the verdict: dead or not dead?
Thanks,
Morten

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would not use that or trust that to hold at 90psi. I'm not sure how that's happened unless it's been ridden while flat or it's a fake continental tire, that's certainly been used

Comment: It could be a fake (see the irregular red yellow stripes) that has been made unusable, but somehow 'salvaged' and sold.

Comment: I don't think it is a fake. I bought it second hand from a trustworthy person, who has gone tubeless. He also reimbursed me. So no harm done in that respect.

Comment: It is inflated to 90psi as photographed, btw. I don't know how it ended up in this poor condition, but would like to get opinions on, if it is safe to use for training

Comment: Sliding the sidewall against sharp rock or curb does that kind of damage. Don't ask how I know.

Comment: It might get you ten miles, but I wouldn't bet on 100.

Comment: @Jensen any chance you can post a picture from the top angle, I am interested to see the tread pattern, Grand Prix Continentals have a distinct pattern.

Comment: If you reinforce the cut and use the tire on the rear wheel only it could be okay. But ride carefully and expect to be stranded somewhere.

Comment: Really, Michael? Really, anyone else? Would you say the same if you thought you could be held to account?

Never having actually seen that tyre, you'd stake your professional reputation as some kind of tyre specialist on "… reinforce the cut and use the tire on the rear wheel only it could be okay. But ride carefully…"? Really?

Professional or not, you'd be happy if a court awarded damages based against that advice? Really?

Comment: People - answers in answers please.  Comments bypass the up/down vote process.

Comment: First two, borderline, have fixed and ridden a tyre to death (via tread loss) with cuts like that. Third one: nope, my face is worth more than even the cost of a new GP5000  :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would not ride that tyre.  Pretty sure I can see tube in the second photo, and that's asking for a sudden blowout.

You might choose to put a boot/patch on the inside of the tyre, JUST TO GET HOME.

You might boot it and use on an *indoor* trainer tyre only.   Might be okay on rollers, would make a great front-wheel tyre for a direct-drive trainer (ie, the wheel that doesn't turn at all.)

I certainly would not choose to ride on the road with that ever.

***It is dead, buy a new tyre.***

Comment: It does look a lot like tube in the 2nd picture, but in that case there's no pressure in it.  I've caused similar damage and the tube was bulging out (a boot got me home then I retired the almost new tyre)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only to the nearest tire shop. While doing so, put the tire boots in your emergency tire repair kit to the inside of the tire, at the areas where the cuts are. Tire boots weigh next to nothing (three Park Tool TB-2 boots weigh 8 grams), and are also reasonably cheap, in fact so cheap that you shouldn't consider reusing them.

Tire boots are marvelous items, they can turn a tire with a full cut causing the tube to burst, into a tire that is able to contain an inflated tube inside. It's extremely rare to destroy your tire in such a manner that a boot wouldn't at least temporarily fix it.

If you find the tire contains the tube without boots, don't take your chances, use boots nevertheless. It's possible the situation worsens during the trip to the nearest tire shop, and that the tire would suddenly finally cut, and the tube would suddenly explode, causing rapid deflation.

Comment: Booting a cut is a great get-home fix.  I have several times tried to ride on with a boot, and they fail within a couple hundred kilometres as the boot and tube get pushed through the ever-enlarging hole, thought this is at road-tyre pressures of 80-90 PSI.  The cut/tear just slowly grows till the tube and boot is hearneating through

Comment: @Criggie curious what you used for the boot. I have had good (luck?) forgetting about boots made from US paper currency and others from Cliff Bar wrappers.

Comment: @PaulH I generally have a plastic coin bag in my toolkit, with USB cables in it.  They work well.  I've also used gel pouches, but they tend to be messy... you can never get them completely empty so they leak some in side the tyre.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it is a simple as that:

If there is any kind of deformation (as clearly shown on the groove above the cut): The tire is structurally impaired and ready to go into the bin. Same for any kind of damage that makes the tube shine through or bulge out. It *will eventually fail* and you're just waiting for it to do so.

I've been there and finished rides on damaged tires, but as soon as you are starting to think about whether your tires make it through the next ride, don't overthink and replace it.

Even a high-spec racing tire isn't worth waiting for it to fail big time, we're talking about replacement in the range or 50€/$/£, a fatal crash will cost far more if you just scratch your derailleur and bar tape. Therapies and job loss not included...

Answer (score -2):

Of course not.

Why are you risking your life on the word of a bunch of internet strangers you're never going to meet or be able to hold accountable?

Go to a qualified specialist and have the suspect tyre examined…

Whatever else, please remember that if it does fail and any kind of law-enforcement finds out you Posted this query, you will have no weakest wheel to stand on.

Comment: What are you talking about? You do realize that this is a bicycle tire, not a car or motorcycle tire, right? Taking a spill from a bike is very rarely life-threatening, there wouldn't be any passengers, and law enforcement is not going to know or care that some bicyclist somewhere had a blow-out.

Comment: @Swifty yes, that's not the sort of tyre you'd be likely to use on a kid-carrying bike

Comment: Yeah I messed that comment up, got all excited. Rubbie I was actually trying to bridge the gap and bring the focus back to the good point I think you are trying to make, that we should think about others and not only ourselves. Do note that the other answer very clearly says not to use the tyre, it has had a lot of upvotes and has been accepted by the asker - indicating they will be heeding this advice.

Comment: @Swiftly Cool; thanks

Comment: @HiddenWindshield I will point out that this is a top-quality racing tire. There’s a very real possibility the OP will be riding at speeds high enough to cause severe injuries in the event of a crash.

Answer (score -2):

Not hard workaround repair. Had similar with very long cut (whole side) on my loved Conti.

1st tried to glue from inside, but after some time or increasing pressure (often over 6 bar) tube went out again...
Then found way better method - used plastic foil (peas package) around tube and tyre is reliable again ;-)
[image: Continental]

---

Also similar problem after 2 simultaneous ~3-5 mm long punctures / cuts of old Schwalbe - yellow puncture strip and tube was visible and soon went flat again - placed next tread cut from an old tyre inside and seems to work fine too, tire has a bit wider shape now, but would tell there is no noticable riding difference (front wheel).
[image: Schwalbe]

---

Few thousand km later, still no problems except 1 puncture, top speeds 55-59km/h (downhill), front wheel.
[image: 1st thread Schwalbe] [image: 2nd thread Schwalbe]

---

After another 400km big holes and strange shape, but still working ;-)
[image]

---

Was curious how much longer it can run, 2 weeks/300km and then hole extended, finished last 15km ride, it was knocking fender a bit and jumping in slower speed, but arrived complete ;-)
[image: Last before replacement]

Anyway it looks like hard broken tread is problem, but side with good tube support inside may not be at all - 3 years from fix / 12t km and no problems still.

Still riding the Conti (cut almost new 12/2019); daily commuting at least 12t km sum and no big problems, best fix was a thin flat piece cut from low resistance mountain tyre, inflating to 7-8 bars still and sometimes 50-68km/h downhill top speeds, back wheel for some time yet.
[image: 4 years cut Conti]

Comment: Remember tyres are wear items - they are consumable.  When they're this bad, its time to start shopping for new ones.

Comment: Sure, but would tell better tyre with additional layer may still work better than average or cheap one and there is low load on front wheel and point is you can do miracles with tube ex. and do not worry about cut in sidewall for example. It is kind of demonstration tyre with bit of tube support can easily stand way more you can imagine (would tell questioned one for sure). Also any bigger puncture will break tyre too and can quickly lead to next one - is anyone interested in ex. replacing both tyre and tube after each puncture ?

Comment: I have one boring 26" tube in my rotation.  At last count it has 15 patches on it and they all work fine.  Patching tubes is a normal activity for any cyclists, and more-so for high distance riders.   I would not be riding that tyre at 50+ km/h.